# Which TDataSet, TDbGrid events to use for implementing an Un-Do feature

Tags: delphi

I'm planning to write an un-do feature for use in a TDBGrid hooked up to a TTable (BDE). I want it to work at the grid cell level.

I'd like some suggestions on a good way to implement this.

I plan to keep a list of records that changed, the field name, and their former values.

What I need, I believe, are an OnEnter and OnExit for *cells*.

TDataSet.BeforeEdit is half of what I need, I think. But, TDataSet.AfterEdit is a bit misnamed -- it's called not after the edit is completed, but "after the TDataSet enters the edit mode" (to quote the help system.)

TField.OnChange would work though... I think ...

My thinking is that AfterEdit will grab the contents of the cell. And TField.OnChange will log the change to a stack I keep. (Thank goodness for Delphi's Generics.  I never knew what I was missing before we had them!)

Any suggestions on how my thinking, caveats, or better ways to do this?

PS Standard mea culpa: Yes, yes: the BDE is deprecated, I shouldn't be using it, yada, yada, yada.  Tell that to my boss who has me maintaining 1.5 million lines of legacy code. Yes, yes: someday the BDE will go away and we should be proactive and make the move now. We know. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to track and undo edits which didn't get updated to the database yet. Why not track and undo Posts?  You plan to allow an Undo to operate on an in-memory edit that you could just cancel?

Comment: regarding BDE: not, it will never go away ;) - see [Demotivators](http://despair.com/viewall.html)

Comment: Don't cells already support undo by typing Ctrl-Z or Esc? Or do you want to keep a stack of edits to multiple cells and have "undo" revert them one by one? Haven't looked at the vcl code, but for that you may be better off looking at the TField events?

Comment: @Warren: like Excel's un-do, I want the granularity of the un-do to be at the cell level, not the row/record level.

Comment: @Marjan: Yes, I want to keep a stack of changes. As I note in my OP, TField.Onchange gives me control I need immediately *after* the edit. I haven't found a way to get control so I can grab the value of the cell *before* they start editing.

Comment: @RobertFrank: Then you will have to combine dataset and field events. The dataset onbeforeedit will give you the base for all cells, each field's onchange will give you its afteredit which would render the same value as an (imaginary) field.onbeforeedit when the user comes back to edit the same cell again.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: if you post your comment as an answer, I will flag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Robert's request, my comment(s) rewritten as an asnwer.

Don't cells already support undo by typing Ctrl-Z or Esc?

Or if you want to keep a stack of edits to multiple cells and have "undo" revert them one by one then you could combine dataset and field events. The dataset `OnBeforeEdit` will give you the base for all cells, each field's onchange will give you its `OnAfterEdit` which would render the same value as an (imaginary) `Field.OnBeforeEdit` when the user comes back to edit the same cell again.

Answer (score 1):

1. If to implement Undo / Redo functionality for BDE datasets, then best will be to inherit your own datasets, and there override some methods, instead of to hook events. Then replace all `TQuery` with `TYourQuery`.
2. More simple is to use `TClientDataSet` + `TDataSetProvider` in the places where Undo / Redo is needed. Set `TClientDataSet`.`LogChanges` to True. To Undo editing call `UndoLastChange`. Sorry, you cannot Redo, although.
3. Migration from BDE to some 3d party data access components may be simple and straightforward. Eg, [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) has API compatible with BDE, well [documented](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/Migrating_BDE_applications.html) migration procedure, tool for automating migration. Also, after migration you will get (2) right out of the box.

Comment: +1. Implementing additional features and digging a deeper BDE-transition hole is not the solution to your boss' intransigence over your current staggering technical debt.  The boss WANTS a new feature; Undo/Redo.  Voila, you have your justification for the BDE-removal.